# How to add list to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I add an already existing list into a dictionary?

Specifically, if I have:

```
lst = [["Hi"],["Monty"],["Python"],["snake"],["Anaconda"]]
```

And I was looking to get:

```
d = {0: "Hi", 1: "Monty", 2: "Python", 3: "snake", 4: "Anaconda"}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use `for key, val in enumerate list` to generate the index-value pairings.  Then follow the various duplicate answers as you wish.

Comment: I'd vote to keep this question as a non-duplicate. The other linked question requires a int conversion too which adds complexity. Simple is good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dict(enumerate(lst))
```

is your friend!

in your case:

```
dict(enumerate(itertools.chain.from_iterable((lst))))
```

Comment: This will have lists as dictionary values, but OP wants strings (ie, the zeroeth element of each list)

Comment: You are right @Joel. added a `chain` now :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension). You can get the index of the sublist using the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

```
lst = [["Hi"],["Monty"],["Python"],["snake"],["Anaconda"]]
d = {i: sublist[0] for i, sublist in enumerate(lst)}
```

You can also add each list item using a for loop.

```
d = {}
for i, sublist in enumerate(lst):
    d[i] = sublist[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
newdict = {}
for i, j in enumerate(lst):
    newdict[j] = i[0]
print(newdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists where each of the inner lists is holding one string.  To turn that into a dictionary holding only the string, you will need to explicitly iterate through each item.  You can do this with a dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {i: val[0] for i, val in enumerate(lst)}
```

or

```
d = {(i, val[0]) for i, val in enumerate(lst)}
```

Here we iterate over each index, inner list pair with val[0] taking the string out of the inner list.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.